# How can I retain German permanent residence if I need to leave the country?

Tags: germany, residency

I am a permanent resident of Germany with Indian citizenship. I have some problems in India and I have to go back to India. If I stay away longer than 6 months, my German status will be cancelled.

What is the procedure so that I can stay in india and maintain status in Germany.  As I may need to back in future, how could I come and live in Germany? Could I buy property in Germany, like a house and register my name there, but still live in India? What if I visited Germany in another year?

I'm looking for a solution so that I don't lose my status.

Comment: To avoid ambiguity, can you clarify whether you hold a Niederlassungserlaubnis or an Aufenthaltserlaubnis?

Comment: We also need to know how long you have been in Germany and how old you are.

Comment: I have a similar concern.
I'm a non-EU citizen, 32 years of age. I did my masters in Germany (IT) for 3 years, after which I got my Bluecard for 3.5+ years now. I'm applying for a Permanent Residence Permit (Niederlassungserlaubnis). Due to family reasons I have to leave Germany for more than 6 months. Can you guide me on how long can I stay outside of Germany without losing my PR?
@phoog
Thanks a bunch!